# How do the error terms in the Legendre Sieve become large?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

I know I have made a mistake! But I can't figure out where, and I'm just hoping someone can explain where/why.

The Legendre Sieve, if we use the floor function, gives the formula

$$\pi_L(x) = \pi(x) - \pi(\sqrt{x}) + 1 = \sum_{d \mid P} \mu(d)\left[\frac{x}{d}\right] \tag{1}$$

Where $d \mid P$ indicates the set of divisors (including $1$) of $P = p_n\text{#} = p_1p_2 \cdots p_n$, with $p_1 = 2$ and $p_n$ being the largest prime $p_n \leq \sqrt{x}$.

Of course the floor function is untidy (and not multiplicative), so we want to replace it with:

$$\left[\frac{x}{d} \right] = \frac{x}{d} - \varepsilon(d)$$

Where $\varepsilon(d)$ is the error between the division and the floor function, bounded by $0 \leq \varepsilon(d) \leq (1 - \frac{1}{d})$. The bound on this error term does not depend on $x$; if we choose a large $x$ and divide it by $3$, the error $\varepsilon(3)$ will always be in $\{0, \frac13, \frac23\}$. Now we can rewrite $(1)$ as

$$\pi_L(x) = \sum_{d \mid P} \mu(d)\left(\frac{x}{d} - \varepsilon(d) \right) = \color{red}{x \sum_{d \mid P} \mu(d)\frac{1}{d}} - \color{blue}{\sum_{d \mid P} \mu(d) \varepsilon(d)} \tag{2}$$

The Euler product version of this is then:

$$\pi_L(x) = \color{red}{x \prod_{2 \leq p}^{p_n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)} - \color{blue}{(-1)^n \prod_{2 \leq p}^{p_n} \varepsilon(p)} \tag{3}$$

Since $\varepsilon(1) = 0$, the Euler product of the second term results in simply $-\varepsilon(p)$ for each prime used, giving the alternating sign. Because we know $0 \leq \varepsilon(p) \leq (1 - \frac{1}{p}) < 1$, the total error term (in blue) should be bounded by $|\varepsilon| < 1$. We know this is not the case, and that this error term becomes large quickly. Therefore, I've done **something** wrong in the midst of my math.

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong? Is there some substitution that fails due to some non-obvious (to me) assumption? Is the problem that $\varepsilon(x)$ is not multiplicative? If not, it should still be bounded by $|\varepsilon| < 2^{n-1}$ (where $\varepsilon = \sum \mu(d)\varepsilon(d)$ in equation $(2)$), and on average much closer to $0$ than to the bounds, with the chance of being closer to $0$ higher as $x$ increases. Though maybe not provably closer? (Empirically, $|\varepsilon| < 1$ for $x < 60$.)

(The bound on non-multiplicative $\varepsilon$ comes from having alternating values of $\mu(d)$ as more primes are used. There are $\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{3} + \cdots = 2^{n-1}$ error terms with $\mu(d) = -1$, and $\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{4} + \cdots = 2^{n-1} - 1$ error terms with $\mu(d) = 1$. The largest possible error is then $-2^{n-1}$, if all the positive error terms are $0$. (We can safely assume there's no error term on $\frac{x}{1}$).)

Comment: It’s not true that $\epsilon(d)$ doesn’t depend on $x$, however that’s not the error as $x$ doesn’t change within a given summation.  Your error appears to be assuming that $\epsilon$ is multiplicative, which as you note severely underestimates the error terms.

Comment: Poking around empirically a bit more gives some interesting results. For $3 < x < 2000, |\varepsilon| < \log x + 2$. Which... is not a bad bound at all, really. But if we can only show it empirically, I guess that's not useful. Interestingly, there's a good amount of structure in the error as well; the difference in the errors of $x$ and $x+1$ is often equal to the last term in the partial product $\prod 1 - \frac{1}{p}$.  Currently letting sagemath crunch numbers above $x=2000$, but $|\mathcal{P}(x)|$ starts to get into the $10^{25}$ range at $x=10000$ which will limit the data.

Comment: Now observe that $2^n$ is, in fact, very large compared to the main term.  Consider that $n$ is roughly equal to $\sqrt x/\log x$, so $2^n$ is exponentially larger than $x$ itself.  You are right to observe that there is a lot of cancellation in practice.  But the entire challenge of much analytic number theory lies in showing that cancellations that *should* happen if they were truly random actually **do** happen.  Conspiracies of error terms can be very difficult to rule out conclusively.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, showing the cancellations cancel does seem to be the tricky part! That said, I'm unsure how $\varepsilon(d)$ should depend on $x$... oh wait, I was unclear, I mean that the *bound* on $\varepsilon(d)$ doesn't depend on $x$. Different statements... (Edited the OP to change this)